# Invert motor block in EV3

Tags: programming, motor, ev3

New to EV3 so this should be simple. I would like my simple wheeled robot to go backwards. So I put two invert motor blocks, one for port B the other for port C followed by a move steering block. The motors ran forwards! I then tried an invert motor black followed by a large motor block and that worked just fine. Does invert motor not work with move steering or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

In EV3, use a negative number for the power to go backwards.

Comment: Fantastic. So simple when you know how!

Answer (score 2):

We experimented with the invert motor block at the beginning of this year's FLL season with disappointing results. The invert motor block only worked with the large motor block and not the move steering or move tank blocks.

Use a negative number in the power field to go in reverse.

Comment: So any ideas as to how to get move steering/move tank blocks to drive in reverse?